# Animate zoom factor programmatic in a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, storyboard, winrt-xaml

Is there a way that I can animate changing the zoom factor of a ScrollViewer for Windows Runtime?

I'd like to be able to have an image inside one respond to a tapped event by returning to a default zoom of 1.  While it seems that in Windows 8.1 [Change View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn252763.aspx) lets you animate the scrolling, not the zooming I'd like to be able to animate both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to take a part of the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) which has a functioning example and an extension for ScrollViewer which does just this.

Also by setting the ScrollViewer to have size of Auto and simply re-sizing the width properties of whatever element is contained within you can achieve largely the same effect.

Comment: Your link is broken